# Realtime sharing of Website content to other user

Tags: django, webrtc, openlayers, real-time, screensharing

I have a django web application with  a map view using openlayers.  I have to develop a map sharing screen in real time to other user in the application for the real time view/suggestion for the edit. How to develop the real time web content sharing system.

Comment: have you tried django channels ?

Comment: No. my content is gis map.  I need to share the map div to other user while i editing the features.